# Sending events form edge-device to ditto via hono

Tags: eclipse-hono, eclipse-ditto

I did followings successfully:

- Creating a hono tenant and registering a device for it.
- Connecting a simple python based edge-device to hono.
- Connecting hono to ditto.
- Creating a twin for the above edge-device.

Sending telemtery data from the edge-device to ditto through hono works perfectly.

I also **send a pseudo event** every second **form edge-device to ditto through hono** as follows:

```py
# sending an event from edge-device to ditto through hono-mqtt-adapter
correlation_id = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=10))
data = {
    "topic": "de.iot1/dev1/things/live/messages/fire",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "text/plain",
        "correlation-id": correlation_id
     },
     "path": "/outbox/messages/fire",
     "value": "Fire detected"
}
payload = json.dumps(data)
mqtt_client.publish("event", payload=payload, qos=1)
```

On the other side I wrote a simple ditto-amqp-client which just receives all dittos incomming messages. I receive all incoming telemetry messages as their correct interval - i.e. every second. In the case of events messages they seems to be buffered by ditto and sent to amqp-client every couple of seconds and not at the time they are send from the device! Why?

As far as I understood from the [ditto-doc](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/protocol-twinlive.html), ditto offers two communication channels. twin-channel for communicating with the twin through commands and events and a live-channel to communicate with the device directly through messages. But in the section [protocol-topics](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/protocol-specification-topic.html)
the channel can be either twin or live also for events or commands, which is confusing.

- I would like to know what is the recommended way to send an event form the device to ditto?
- Should one send it through live channels using events or messages (outbox)?
- Is it better to define the event as a feature in the twin and send normal command/modify to its value?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: >  In the case of events messages they seems to be buffered by ditto and sent to amqp-client every couple of seconds and not at the time they are send from the device! Why?
...
I did not get your setup. Do you use Ditto to also publish (peristed) twin events to an AMQP 1.0 endpoint and your "ditto-amqp-client" consumes from that AMQP endpoint? 
Because Ditto itself does not provide an AMQP endpoint.
If that is the case I would have a look at the AMQP broker as Ditto does not buffer/batch applied events but directly sends them out.

Comment: @ThomasJäckle yes, exactly, I wrote a simple amqp-client which acts like a pseudo broker. I also created a ditto-amqp connection for this client. Ditto just publishes all messages to this amqp-connection.  But what is in your opinion the right way to publish devic events. Using live/events or live/messages or twin/command/modify and declaring a event-feature in the twin? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I receive all incoming telemetry messages as their correct interval - i.e. every second. In the case of events messages they seems to be buffered by ditto and sent to amqp-client every couple of seconds and not at the time they are send from the device! Why?

As Ditto does not do a "store-and-forward", but publishes applied events immediately, I can't really explain from Ditto side. Maybe by sending events (which in Hono are persisted using an AMQP broker), those are consumed with some delay (after persisted by the broker), however I can't explain the "every couple of seconds".
You could enable DEBUG logging in Ditto's connectivity service by setting the environment variable `LOG_LEVEL_APPLICATION` to `DEBUG` - that way you'll see when the messages are received and when they are forwarded again to your AMQP endpoint.

> - I would like to know what is the recommended way to send an event form the device to ditto?
> - Should one send it through live channels using events or messages (outbox)?

When you talk about the "fire detected" event (containing a payload which shall not be stored in a twin managed by Ditto), I would send it as live **message** from the device (using Hono event channel with "QoS 1" - at least once - semantics).
However, an application connected to Ditto (e.g. via Websocket or via HTTP webhook) must be consuming the live message and [acknowledging](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/2020-10-23-end-2-end-acknowledgment.html#scenario-5---long-running-live-message-scenario) that it received the message.

Events in Ditto are the entity which is persisted as part of the [CQRS](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/basic-signals.html#architectural-style) architecture style. After persisting, interested parties can be notified about them.
So **live events** are meant to be in the same Ditto [event format](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/basic-signals-event.html) and must not be confused with Hono events.

> - Is it better to define the event as a feature in the twin and send normal command/modify to its value?

It depends on your requirements.
You could also make the "fireDetected" a `boolean` property in a feature and subscribe to changes of this property. But then this should be only settable via the device (using an appropriate Ditto Policy) - and the "QoS 1" guarantees you get by combining Hono and Ditto cannot be used any longer.